# Do Python comments have to be indented the same as surrounding code blocks? (VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation

I'm working on a Python project using VS Code as my editor, and I'm getting a Python indentation error when I place comments in between blocks of code. Specifically:

```
while score0 < goal and score1 < goal:
    if player:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    player = other(player)

# END PROBLEM 5
# BEGIN PROBLEM 6
"*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    say(score0, score1)
```

I'm getting an indentation error when I evoke say(score0, score1), but the error gets fixed if I indent the comments to match the surrounding lines. Is this a general rule in Python, or a requirement of using VS Code?

Comment: same happens with IDLE

Comment: Are you saying the "*** YOUR CODE [...]" line is a comment? because it is not, and is a valid python line of code so it has to match the rest of the code

Answer (score 5):

Lines that do not start with a # are considered code.

So your

```
"*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

Line is actually code, so Python expects code after it to match it's indent (since the while loop is over), and doesn't know why `say` is indented, so it throws the Indentation Error

So this is a Python thing, not a VSCode thing

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multiline comment in python with `"` but it needs to be 3 in a row. An example would be Python's docstrings 
For example, if you had a main module as such:

```py
def main(args):
    """
    Main method for running the selected arguments
    :param args: the arguments that are passed to main
    :return: None
    """
```

That is a valid comment in Python. However, as you noted, you should have it indented correctly. So if you want to keep your comment using `"""`, you can do:

```
while score0 < goal and score1 < goal:
    if player:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    player = other(player)

# END PROBLEM 5
# BEGIN PROBLEM 6
    """*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"""
    say(score0, score1)
```

Note that you do not need to put comments with the `#` on the same indentation as the rest.